# Spawn objects at random durations without overlaying

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

### Explanation

I'm building a game where I'm facing some problems. I have two objects (A and B) that run by the same rule: from up to bottom, they spawn, move heading down and get removed when reach the edge. Each one of them has its particular duration before spawning, this way, sometimes, they get overlayed (as you can see below).

[image]

---

### Question

The question is quite simple: is there any way to make A and B spawn by different durations, but still random ones?

---

### Code

If you want, you can download this project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fc81w0r4vjr7n25/AACGuPhckVmUFhDg6k0Gl_1ja?dl=0).

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    //Declarations
    var A = SKSpriteNode()
    var B = SKSpriteNode()
    var durationA = CGFloat()
    var durationB = CGFloat()

    //Setup
    func setupA(){
        A = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "A")
        A.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height)
    }
    func setupB(){
        B = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "B")
        B.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height)
    }

    //Actions
    func actionsA(){

        //Start spawning, moving and removing
        let spawnA = SKAction.runBlock({
            () in

            //Spawn A
            self.setupA()
            self.addChild(self.A)

            //Move left and remove when go off screenk
            let frameHeight = CGFloat(self.frame.height)
            let moveA = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -frameHeight, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.0028 * frameHeight))  //duration: faster or slower
            let removeA = SKAction.removeFromParent()

            let moveAndRemoveA = SKAction.sequence([moveA, removeA])

            self.A.runAction(moveAndRemoveA)
        })

        //Spawn A each 1.75~2.25 seconds
        durationA = (CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(51)) + 175.0) / 100.0
        let spawnAfterDurationA = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(Double(durationA)), spawnA]))
        runAction(spawnAfterDurationA)
    }
    func actionsB(){

        //Start spawning, moving and removing
        let spawnB = SKAction.runBlock({
            () in

            //Spawn B
            self.setupB()
            self.addChild(self.B)

            //Move left and remove when go off screen
            let frameHeight = CGFloat(self.frame.height)
            let moveB = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -frameHeight, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.0028 * frameHeight))   //duration: faster or slower
            let removeB = SKAction.removeFromParent()

            let moveAndRemoveB = SKAction.sequence([moveB, removeB])

            self.B.runAction(moveAndRemoveB)
        })

        //Spawn B each 0.5~1.0 seconds
        durationB = (CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(51)) + 50.0) / 100.0
        let spawnAfterDurationB = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(Double(durationB)), spawnB]))
        runAction(spawnAfterDurationB)
    }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        actionsA()
        actionsB()
    }
}
```

---

### Timothy Smith's attempt

If you want, you can download it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r37kvw1vr6qdllc/AABFFN4ntRGmjYH45BQwwR0aa?dl=0).

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    //Declarations
    var A = SKSpriteNode()
    var B = SKSpriteNode()

    //Setup
    func setupA(){
        A = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "A")
        A.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height)
    }
    func setupB(){
        B = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "B")
        B.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height)
    }

    //Actions
    func actionsA(){

        //Spawn, move and remove
        let spawnA = SKAction.runBlock({
            () in

            //Spawn A
            self.setupA()
            self.addChild(self.A)

            //Move left and remove when go off screenk
            let frameHeight = CGFloat(self.frame.height)
            let moveA = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -frameHeight, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.0028 * frameHeight))  //duration: faster or slower
            let removeA = SKAction.removeFromParent()

            let moveAndRemoveA = SKAction.sequence([moveA, removeA])

            self.A.runAction(moveAndRemoveA)
        })

        runAction(spawnA)
    }
    func actionsB(){

        //Spawn, move and remove
        let spawnB = SKAction.runBlock({
            () in

            //Spawn B
            self.setupB()
            self.addChild(self.B)

            //Move left and remove when go off screen
            let frameHeight = CGFloat(self.frame.height)
            let moveB = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -frameHeight, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.0028 * frameHeight))   //duration: faster or slower
            let removeB = SKAction.removeFromParent()

            let moveAndRemoveB = SKAction.sequence([moveB, removeB])

            self.B.runAction(moveAndRemoveB)
        })

        runAction(spawnB)
    }

    //Spawn
    func spawn(){

        let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(10)+1) //pick a number from 1 to 10

        if random <= 8{
            actionsB()
        }
        else{
            actionsA()
        }
    }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5, withRange: 0.25), SKAction.runBlock(self.spawn)])))
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Luiz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use a single function `spawn`, called randomly every 0.25 to 1.00 seconds. Inside the function, randomly pick either A or B, and spawn it. It appears that you want B to appear more frequently than A, so you could use a weighted randomness (pick a number from 0.45 to 1 and round to the nearest integer).

Whether this works depends on whether it is acceptable to have a B-separation of more than 1 second.

Comment: I followed the steps as you said, but when you say to pick a number from 0.45 to 1 and round to the nearest integer, I think I'd only have zeros and ones, wouldn't I? So I picked a random number from 1 to 10, and spawn B when <=8 (and spawn A when > 8), this way B will appear more frequently than A. This being said, it is still spawning at the same time (overlaying) =(

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood something, I'm just trying to help you to help me =)

Comment: I updated the code with your suggestion. If it helps, you can also download the project there.

Comment: You would have either a 0 or a 1. If it's 0, spawn A, otherwise spawn B. Currently what you're doing is calling actionsA. Keep in mind that actionsA doesn't actually spawn anything: it creates a randomly repeating cycle, which spawns on its own. I'm not familiar with the language, but I think you could modify the last line in actionsA to say this:  `runAction(spawnA)` And that may solve the problem.

Comment: When I round the random value between 0.45 and 1.00, I have 99% of chance to get 0 and 1% of chance to get 1, but it’s weirdly returning more ones than zeros when rounded (I did test to see the results without rounding, and 1.00 is very uncommon). If we follow the “right” rule and establish that when rounding we should get more zeros than ones, since `B` should appear more often than `A`, `actionsB` would be called when 0 (99% of chance) and `actionsA` when 1 (1% of chance).

Comment: I don’t get why you say that `actionsA` doesn’t spawn. When called, it was basically calling `spawnA`, which adds `A` into the scene, moves it to end of the screen and removes when reaching it, after a random duration. As spawn function (where `actionsA` or `actionsB` is called) is called “forever”, I had removed the `repeatActionForever` from `actionsA` and `actionsB`, so it wouldn’t spawn triplicately.

Comment: Anyway, your suggestion pretty much let me to the solution. Since each object had its own duration and the `spawn` function also had its duration, the durations where triplicated. This way, causing the objects to spawn at different times and basically “disabling” the `spawn`’s duration role on the system. So if we remove the objects’ durations, it’ll run perfectly, since it’s now running above only one duration: the `spawn`’s one.

Comment: Awesome, looks good! Yeah, I wasn't entirely clear on what I meant. Glad it helped though!

Comment: If you round a random value between 0.45 and 1.00 using `round()`, there is a 9% chance that it will be 0 and 91% chance it will be 1. This is because it rounds _up_ for all values greater than 0.5.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to use `Int(value)`, you can do this: `Int(value + 0.5)` and that will round to the nearest value (so 0.2 >> 0.0, 0.48 >> 0.0, 0.5 >> 1.0, and 0.9 >> 1.0)

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that. Thank you again =)

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you run `(arc4random_uniform(50)+51)/100` it will give you a random duration between 0.5 and 1.0 seconds. you can use below code to generate random durantions for `A` & `B`

`durationA = (arc4random_uniform(50)+51)/100
durationB = (arc4random_uniform(50)+51)/100`

Additionally, you can run a for loop to compare durationB with durationA and only accept `durationB` if it is not the same as `durationA`.

Comment: I just tried to do it, but it isn't spawning any child. All I did was use the durations as you said and apply it on the action. I updated the code.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer. I've been kinda busy this week.

Comment: After some research, I managed to make it spawn. But as I'm using 1.75 to 2.25 for `durationA` and 0.5 to 1.0 for `durationB`, these numbers will never be the same, this way, it will never enter the loop, but will keep spawning in the same position sometimes.